# Mysql query deleimiter in a file

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

In the following query if desc has "\" in it and this file when opened by openoffice the \ and appears in a different coulmn.This also happens with city column,How to recitfy this..

```
select first_name, last_name, emp_id,desc,city from emp_table where event_id = 4 order by city asc   into OUTFILE "/tmp/Sep10-1.csv"   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `ESCAPED BY` clause to escape special characters in dump.

```
select 
  first_name, last_name, emp_id,desc,city 
from 
  emp_table 
where 
  event_id = 4 
order by 
  city asc   
into OUTFILE 
  "/tmp/Sep10-1.csv"   
FIELDS 
  TERMINATED BY "," 
  ESCAPED BY "\";
```